# How to release through a Build server with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, release

At the moment we use Maven just to build SNAPSHOTs. These SNAPSHOTs are "released" by some other tool that pushes them to another Nexus repository.

We would prefer to have a way to directly build releases that fulfils the following criteria:

1. It checks whether all dependencies are release versions.
2. It is reasonably fast.
3. It does not play dirty tricks with Maven or hacks around some core Maven mechanisms.

I am asking for a solution - this need not be a given tool, I am willing to do some programming myself. That said, I read about the Maven-Release-Plugin, which seems to be established, but people also rant against it (being slow, not being the right method to be run on a build server,...).

What would be a reasonable approach?

Comment: Have you looked at Jenkins or any similar deployment tool?

Comment: I have successful run the Maven release plugin in Jenkins without problems.

Comment: Requirement #2 is meaningless, "reasonably fast" does not have a standard definition. In a hefty code base with dozens of integration tests 30 minutes is still reasonably fast; in a code base which only compiles it is probably very slow. #3 has the same problem, there is no definition for a dirty trick or a hack. The release plugin itself is one large dirty trick, but it works... mostly.

Comment: First to say the maven-release-plugin works very well. It has some prerequisites yes. You can of course implement the steps yourself (checkout, check for SNAPSHOT's, change version via versions-maven-plugin, checkin, make the tags and make the build by  `mvn deploy` afterwards incrementing the version number via versions-maven-plugin and checkin the second time which is needed). At the moment releasing a multi module build with 800 modules (ca. 1.5 million lines of code) within 10 minutes (checkout takes 5 min). Not running any tests during the release build...cause they have ran before.

Comment: What do you mean by #3 ?